# C# ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory Encoding

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, zip

I have a french file "Dans mes rêves.mp3". In C#, when I use `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("/path/to/folder/with/FrenchMp3", "ArchiveName.zip")` I see in the generated zip file "Dans mes rÛves.mp3".

Seems to be the encoding ? How can I resolve this ?

I tried the following and it did not work:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("/path/to/folder/with/FrenchMp3", "ArchiveName.zip",CompressionLevel.Optimal, false, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

In the debugger the file name really shows "Dans mes rêves.mp3".

Comment: `iso-8859-1` doesn't have complete coverage of all French characters. Have you tried a different encoding?

Comment: Well I'm not so familar with encoding, but I tried `UTF8`, `Unicode`, `iso-8859-1` up to `iso-8859-5`

Comment: Try using Encoding.GetEncoding(850). Weirdly enough this worked for scandinavian characters where the ususal ISO-8859-1 and 1252 did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("/path/to/folder/with/FrenchMp3", "ArchiveName.zip",CompressionLevel.Optimal, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(850));
```

with "Dans mes rêves.mp3" and it works correctly.

Comment: Following this answer I wondered what was 850 stand for. After a bit of googling, I found this interesting Web site in case some one ever needs it:https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp850.html